# ASP:Dropdown List producing duplicate value on button click while data binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have a `asp:dropdown` defined as below:

```
<asp:Label ID="DropdownLabel1" runat="server">State Name</asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="statename" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="600px" style= "top:100%;" Enabled ="false">
      <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have a button function which is defined as below:

```
<asp:Button ID="Savestate" runat="server" Text=" Save " 
OnClick="SaveState_Click"></asp:Button>
```

By clicking this button, it will invoke the function `SaveState_Click` from server side (`.cs` file)

I am trying to bind values to the `dropdown` list from a `dictionary` which is `getStateName`. The keys of `getStateName` holds all the state names and hence using that to bind the value.

Populate function:

```
statename.DataSource = getStateName.Keys;
statename.DataBind();
statename.SelectedIndex = statename.Items.IndexOf(statename.Items.FindByText(GetKeyFromValue(getStateName[1].Id)));
```

The above populate dropdown function works perfectly and binds all the key values to the dropdown list and also selects correct index value as I expect.

But when I click the button again, button function calls the populate function again and the `databind` causes the `dropdown` value to repeat. How many ever times, the button is clicked the dropdown value repeats that many times. 
When I click the button, values in the dropdown list gets replicated. Initially there are 10 values, when I click the button again, the values gets repeated and it has 20 values now (each value gets populated twice), when I click next time, it has 30 values (each value gets populated thrice)

I saw a post to include `enableviewstate= "false"` as an extra parameter and when I did that, dropdown value does not repeat, but selected dropdown value comes as a null value when I try to get it in .cs file.

I also saw another post to include `SecurityQuestion2.AppendDataBoundItems = false;` after `databind`, and I couldn't succeed

I tried below if statement and couldnt succeed either.

```
if (statename.Items.Count <= 1)
      {
         statename.DataSource = getStateName.Keys;
         statename.DataBind();
       }
```

How to prevent this duplication while doing `databind`?

Comment: what is `getStateName` and where it is populated? Please include the code that you are used to populate this dictionary variable

Comment: getStateName is a dictionary which I am using in my .cs file and its key value holds state name.

Comment: Seems like `getStateName` is populated with duplicates, could you please include the code that  you are using to populate the `getStateName`

Comment: It calls various internal function to populate the dictionary and its hard to have all function written here. I dont have any issues with the dictionary. Totally there are 10 values for state I checked the dictionary and all the time it holds only 10 key value pair.

Comment: Now your issue is, it is not selecting the desired element from code behind, right?

Comment: My issue is when I click the button, values in the dropdown list gets replicated. Initially its 10 values, when I click the button again, the values gets repeated and it has 20 values now (each value gets populated twice), when I click next time, it has 30 values (each value gets populated thrice)

Answer (score 1):

Re-write your statement like this, debug it and see which one is creating issue.
Comment this line and break it into few lines :

```
statename.SelectedIndex = statename.Items.IndexOf(statename.Items.FindByText(GetKeyFromValue(getStateName[1].Id)));
```

Change to:

```
string text=statename.Items.FindByText(yourText);//Any value that exists within your dropdown just for testing purpose.
string id=getStateName[1].Id;//change string to int if its an int type
string value=GetKeyFromValue(getStateName[1].Id);
```

Now check the values of these temporaly created variables by putting a breakpoint at the very first line, press F10 and see whether they contains any value or not, if not then track why they are not giving expected results.

Although it is not the solution but It may help you to track what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> getStateName = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    getStateName.Add(3,"New York");
    getStateName.Add(2,"Chicago");
    getStateName.Add(1,"Washington");
    getStateName.Add(0,"Toronto");
    statename.DataSource = getStateName;
    statename.DataTextField = "Value";
    statename.DataValueField = "Key";   
}
```

and button click event

```
protected void SaveState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    statename.DataBind();
}
```

and ....

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="statename" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
        Width="600px" style= "top:100%;"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: And make enableViewstate="false"

Answer (score 0):

try the enableViewstate="false" it may solve part of the problem, with that dropdownlist. If ViewState is switched off then this will no longer happen, because the values are not remembered between Postbacks. Instead, the DropDownList gets populated from scratch each time.

Comment: I tried enableViewstate="false". But if I select the value from dropdown list, it is null.
SecurityQuestion1.SelectedItem.Value is turning out to be null